# Simulate click with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a script that assigns tabindex to visible elements on a page. Most of those are form elements but I also needed to add a way to add a div that I use to show/hide a section.

```
<span class="tabInto">Show/Hide</span>
```

I do this with jQuery

```
$(':input:visible, .tabInto').each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1);
});
```

So, when I tab through the form fields I am able to tab into that span as well. Now I need to be able to simulate click action, to expand hidden section, by using keyboard when I am focused on that span. How Can I do that? Is it usually done with Enter or Space bar?..

Comment: $("selector").trigger("click")?

Comment: I'm not sure but you could call `$("filter element").click();`.

Comment: If you use an anchor instead of a span I believe this is default browser functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an anchor tag (with an `href`), then this is default functionality.  Hitting the enter key while the element has focus will trigger the click handler.

You can simulate this same functionality with a `span` in the following way:

```
$("span").click(function () {
    alert("click span");
});

$("span").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).click();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dLmyV/

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(".tabInto").trigger("click")`

This way you fire the 'click' event on the `tabInto` class.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/